# Can't open https site with port 8443

Tags: apache, ssl, https, centos

I move https site from 443 to 8443 because I need 443 for OpenVPN
`iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 171K packets, 16M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED`

`lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P | grep 8443
httpd     8085     root    6u  IPv6  47853      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
httpd     8086      web    6u  IPv6  47853      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)`

`semanage port -l | grep -w '^http_port_t'
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000`

ssl.conf
`Listen 8443 https`

`<VirtualHost iotanet.gr:8443>`

Pls advice what is possible mistake?
P.S. with 443 site works perfect

Comment: how did you enter the address in the address bar?

Comment: @Andra `https://iotanet.gr/`  the same like before then site was on 443 port

Comment: you need to specify the port: `https://iotanet.gr:8443/`

Comment: @Andra I need to have standard access without typing port number

Comment: specify other port for OpenVPN

Comment: ))) ... I need 443